# RadListView with ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, rad

I added ASP.NET image buttons in RadListView read from a DB source and image out RadListView. My problem is I can't get the selected picture from RadButton to image.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="300px" />
<br />
<telerik:RadListView ID="RadListView3" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
    onselectedindexchanged="RadListView3_SelectedIndexChanged"
    OnItemDataBound="RadListView3_ItemDataBound" PageSize="4"
    AllowCustomPaging="True" Skin="Vista">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="80px"
            ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Pic_Path") %>' onclick="ImageButton2_Click" 
            Width="60px" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
```

Can you help me?

```
// ImageButton2_Click
foreach (RadListViewItem item in RadListView3.SelectedItems)
{
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)item.FindControl("ImageButton2");
    Image1.ImageUrl = btn.ImageUrl; 
}
```

Comment: what does your server-side code look like within ImageButton2_Click??

Comment: foreach (RadListViewItem item in RadListView3.SelectedItems)
            {
                ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)item.FindControl("ImageButton2");
                Image1.ImageUrl = btn.ImageUrl; 
            }

Comment: If you are not posting back when the Grid Selection changes then your server-side code will not run.  you should use a client-side event handler for the 'focus' event on each Image in the grid.  I will show a sample

Comment: ok thank you waiting your sample